# mange scrollview for different ImageSize

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `ScrollView` defined in a layout which contains the `ImageSwitcher`

now when a user presses next button or previous button i am changing the images inside 
`ImageSwitcher` dynamically.

Now the issues is i have a different size of images one is short in height and another is long in height. so when first short image is displayed and then long and if i go back then scroll view is occupying the height of long image rather then dimension of short image.

here is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <ScrollView 

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerBar"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/helpPanel"


       >
         <ImageSwitcher android:id="@+id/switcher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />

       </ScrollView>
   </RelativeLayout>
```